# WPF ComboBox databinding ItemsSource item.ToString() to property setter. Why?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

For some reason when I bind a ComboBox to a list of POCOs, the property which is bound to SelectedValue is set twice:

1. With value = POCO.ToString()
2. With value = POCO.Key property, **which is the intended behaviour**

I have the following ComboBox that is bound to properties in my ViewModel:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllowedClassifications}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TargetGroup.Classification}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Key" />
```

The properties in ViewModel are defined as:

```
//ICollection is implemented by ObservableCollection<T>
//DataBaseFieldValue has two public properties: string Key, string Value
public ICollection<DatabaseFieldValue> AllowedClassifications
{
    get { return _allowedClassifications; }
    private set { _allowedClassifications = value; }
}

public Model.TargetGroup TargetGroup
{
    get { return _targetGroup; }
    private set { _targetGroup = value; OnPropertyChanged("TargetGroup"); }
}
```

TargetGroup.Classification is defined as:

```
public string Classification
{
    get { return _classification; }
    set 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Classification: " + value);
        _classification = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Classification"); 
    }
}
```

Debug output:

> Classification:
>   MyNamespace.DatabaseFieldValue
>
> Classification: 2

What's happening here? Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF ComboBox databinding ItemsSource item' .ToString() to property setter. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863664/wpf-combobox-databinding-itemssource-item-tostring-to-property-setter-why)

Comment: Why would you duplicate your question??

Comment: maybe it bound twice? ba-da-boom-pshhh ...

Comment: @decyclone - Needless to say it was unintentional - I had my browser crash while writing the question. I had no idea it got already created.

Comment: @johnny g - Actually made me laugh :)

Comment: @johnny g - +1 for the "ba-da-boom-pshhh" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks OK in your code, except for the fact that according to your XAML the property which is bound to SelectedValue should be set to the POCO.Key value rather than POCO.Value (as you wrote you expected). I have just created a test project with similar setup and everything works.

Alternatively, you could try using SelectedItem property of combobox in combination with ItemTemplate:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllowedClassifications}"    
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TargetGroup.Classification}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In this case the `TargetGroup.Classification` property must be of type `DatabaseFieldValue`.

Comment: Binding to POCO.Key is correct, fixed that in my post. Your example works correctly for me, but unfortunately I can't go redefine my Model objects.

Comment: Exactly for that purpose (not having to redefine model objects for UI) there is the MVVM pattern. Instead of binding directly to the model objects you should create a view model around them and bind it. In a view model you can do whatever the UI requires.

Comment: I couldn't find any reason why my implementation didn't work properly, so ended up implementing a ViewModel for the object - works like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion!